# "the smell heard the singing off of the fragments"

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence from A Farewell To Arms:

> We both went flat and with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell heard the **singing off** of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick.

1. How could the smell be heard? You hear a sound not smell a sound.
2. What does *singing off* mean? I am really clueless of this sentence.

Comment: We flattened ourselves. Our senses were assaulted – by the flash and crump of the shellfire, and the smell [of cordite]; by the singing the fragments made as they flew past, and the rattle of falling brick. / Please restrict 'questions' to single questions in future. Interpretation of lengthier extracts (as here) is off-topic, but will no doubt be welcome on Literature SE.

Comment: You are meant to understand the sentence as though there were another 'we' between 'smell' and 'heard'. _With_ the flash came the smell and the sounds. I don't know exactly what Hemingway meant by 'singing off', but the shell fragments would make a sound flying through the air.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question is closely related to the syntax here, however. I think you're being a bit harsh with the 1 question here. It's not like there's a list! ;)

Comment: The author could be a synesthete, able to transfer perceptions between sight, hearing taste et al. or could be showing sounds of dementia or traumatic brain injury. Or they just be trying to be poetic.

Comment: singing off is quite clever: to sing is used to describe a high-pitched or buzzing, and sing off means the fragment of brick were coming off the brick and making that kind of noise as they did.

Comment: @Mitch .. or the sentence might be structured differently ... ( see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We both went flat and with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick.

The basic structure of the sentence is actually like this, where the single subject *We both* appears with two coordinated verb phrases:

- We [went flat] and [heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick].

The preposition phrase *with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell* is structured like this:

- with [the flash and bump of the burst] and [the smell]

Here we see the preposition *with* occurring with a coordination of two noun phrases. Here the preposition *with* means something like *at the very same time as*. It is an adjunct supplying additional information. It belongs inside the second coordinate of the larger sentence:

- We both [went flat] and [**with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell** heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick].

The sentence would be easier to parse had Hemingway used commas or dahses to mark out the preposition phrase:

- We both went flat and, with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell, heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick.
- We both went flat and—with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell—heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick.

However, neither of these would have been in keeping with Hemingway's style!

---

<sup>The noun *singing* here refers to the high pitched ringing noise made by the fragments.</sup>

Comment: You seem to end  up here [...]  with the flash and bump of the burst and the smell| heard the singing off of the fragments and the rattle of falling brick [...] but start out differently. Just wondering why.

Comment: @Lambie Hi, sorry, I don't quite understand the question. (hard morning and no coffee!) Are you asking why the brackets are in different places at the beginning and end of the post?

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I need some more time to understand it hundred percent but it sure did help me.

Comment: @John Glad it helped. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: I think my reading is like your last two bullet point. That is your final PARSE but your explanations seem to stray away from that instead of taking that structure as a starting point. Why bother with other readings since they clearly do not work...

Comment: @Lambie "Why bother with other readings since they clearly do not work..." <--- Good question. The main reason is that I wanted to show how the OP could make a legitimate parse of the sentence leading to their original infelicitous/confusing reading. Sorry, I missed your comment before  (or you might have changed it, not sure which!)

Comment: @Lambie Taking your comment into account, on consideration I've shortened the post. That any better?

Comment: Thank  you. It was not bad before, but I would have started with the structure you provide in the bullet points, and would have forgone the couldas. (Hope  you got some coffee. :)

Comment: @Lambie Yes, am slowly coming round :)